# Supplying a BiConsumer without a previous Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to read lines from a BufferedReader, have the String split in two and have them supplied to a BiConsumer. Can it be done without previously collecting the two split strings to a Map?

Example:

```
bufferedReader.lines()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.split(",")[0], l -> l.split(",")[1]))
    .forEach(translations1::put);
```

Can this be improved by somehow removing the Collectors.toMap?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to feed a function like `biConsumerFunction(String s1, String s2)` for each splitted line ?

Comment: Yes. AFAIK toMap will create an intermediate Map and use its values to be put into the final Map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is keep the toMap

```
Map<String, String> map = bufferedReader.lines()
                                        .map(l -> l.split(",", 2))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
```

Unless there is a requirement I am missing, `toMap` seems to be worth keeping.

By the way, if you want a functional solution, you should try to avoid `forEach` or any lambda which modifies state. It can work in Java, but if you can avoid it, I believe you should. Functional programming is clearest if you don't have side effects.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting into FP and ran into this problem while benchmarking, as my example took way longer than a traditional for loop and realized it was probably because I was creating an intermediate map and feeding it to my final map.

Comment: @lightlazer split is pretty expensive, adding to temporary maps is relatively cheap. I suspect your problem is you split every line twice.

Comment: @lightlazer: if, for whatever reason, you can’t just use the `Map` returned by `collect`, but have to add to an existing map, you can use `bufferedReader.lines() .map(l -> l.split(",", 2)).forEach(a -> target1.put(a[0], a[1]));`, but the only reason not to find this solution on your own, is thinking too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative could be to call explicitly the method `accept` of your `BiConsumer` as next:

```
bufferedReader.lines()
    .map(line -> line.split(",", 2))
    .forEach(a -> consumer.accept(a[0], a[1]));
```

In your particular case, assuming that `translations1` is a `Map<String, String>`, you could add the key/value pairs to your map using the corresponding `BiConsumer` (proposal from [**Holger**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)):

```
bufferedReader.lines()
    .map(line -> line.split(",", 2))
    .forEach(a -> translations1.put(a[0], a[1]));
```

This will add the new key/value pairs in your map and will replace existing value if you try to put a key/value pair whose key already exists.

Comment: Abusing the supplier by returning the same container on each evaluation is a recipe for lots of trouble. If you can’t avoid accessing an existing collection, stick to `forEach` or `forEachOrdered` to document that issue.

Comment: @Holger in case of a parallel stream indeed you can face issues but what kind of issues can we face with a normal stream? do have an example to share?

Comment: Well, for a sequential stream there is the issue that it doesn’t offer any advantage over the simpler `.forEach(a -> translations1.put(a[0], a[1]))`, but can lead to mistakenly thinking that there was one, e.g. pretend to be parallel friendly. If you see a `forEach` operation, it’ll ring your alarm bells (or should), if you are going to switch to parallel, unlike seeing a `collect`…

Comment: Another scenario is combining this collector with another (e.g. `groupingBy`), which would break, even in sequential execution.